# jMeter distributed system testing over cloud without using Blazemeter?

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, stress-testing, blazemeter

As I know we can do the jMeter distributed system testing using the Blaze Meter. Is there any way to perform distribution testing with out Blaze meter over cloud. If yes, How can we access the server?

Can any one suggest some tutorials please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically blaze meter is used for huge volume of load generation using cloud because such amount of load cannot be generated using single machine.

If you don't want to use Blaze meter (paid) then you can try distributed load testing using JMeter.
Refer this [Distributed Load Testing JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_distributed_testing_step_by_step.pdf)

General idea in distributed load testing is you can create a cluster of some machine with a server(1-N) monitoring on client machines(N). Clients will generate load on target server (which can be anywhere i.e. cloud or private hw). Each client will run JMeter instance i.e. one instance or many instances.

Before you go for distributed Jmeter setup, find out how much load you want to hit on target server. If it is not too high then single machine with powerful hw can do the task for you.

Before running JMeter follow below guideline to utilize maximum resources and generate max load on a single machine.

1. Avoid Reporters - OOM issue
2. Avoid Assertions
3. Avoid Listeners - OOM issue
4. Run in non-gui mode
5. Avoid Graph results(redirect results to file and analyze later)
6. Use latest version of JMeter

Comment: BlazeMeter uses it's own technology on top of JMeter for distributed testing which let's it do things native JMeter can't do such as:

1. Launch distributed tests using servers in multiple geo-locations (native JMeter distributed testing clients must be on the same subnet)

2. Add Mobile network emulation

3. Scale up to VERY large numbers (over one million users and one thousand servers **per test**)

4. Real time reporting that does NOT require any listeners.

I apologize if this looks like a shameless plug (I work for BlazeMeter)

Answer (score 2):

Solutions like Blazemeter or [OctoPerf](https://octoperf.com) are emerging because setting up a JMeter cluster is a time consuming and technical task. There are free alternatives to create an [JMeter EC2 Cluster](https://github.com/oliverlloyd/jmeter-ec2), but it still requires technical knowledge.

Make sure to use an asynchronous batch sample sender to avoid overloading the JMeter master, like explained on the [JMeter best practices page](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html#sendermode).

There is always a trade-off between time and money:

- Free solutions are usually time consuming,
- Paid solutions require to put money on the table but can save you a lot of time and headache.

Choosing the right solution depends on your needs.